# XML Schema element with attribute and anyType children

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am not too familiar with XML schema, but I would like to have a schema allowing an element to have name attribute any type of child.
For example, the element myType:

```
<myType name="type1">
    <value>my value</value>
    <country>US</country>
</myType>
```

I tried (which is obviously not working):

```
<xsd:element name="myType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:anyType">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Answer (score 2):

**This XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myType name="type1">
    <value>my value</value>
    <country>US</country>
</myType>
```

**Is valid per this XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="myType">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:any processContents="lax" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

**Explanation:**

- The [`xsd:any`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#element-any) item allows any element to be a child of `myType`.
- The [`xsd:any/@processContents="lax"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#ref33) setting "instructs an
  XML processor to validate the element content on a can-do basis: It
  will validate elements and attributes for which it can obtain schema
  information, but it will not signal errors for those it cannot obtain
  any schema information."

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue but with the code above I have `Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'` error. Is the answer working for someone ?

Comment: The answer is working for the XML in the question, which only had element children.  If you wish to support any mix of text and element children, add  `mixed="true"` to `xsd:complexType`.